# pass data from oracle apex popup interactive grid to main page lines section

Tags: oracle-apex, interactive-grid

I am working an app, which has header and lines section. I have built header region with a create button. After i enter data into the header region and click on create the lines section appear.
To add data to the lines i have added another button (add lines), When i click on add lines another window opens up which is another interactive grid based on a view.
Requirement is to select multiple lines from this popup window (interactive grid) and these should be added to lines section.

Any inputs would be very helpful.